# permanent background image on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, background-image

I am building a swing interface for drawing overlays over a particular image.  I have [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937403/jpanel-background-image) [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051408/jpanel-with-image-background) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280870/jpanel-with-a-background-image) of how to draw an image on a JPanel, and I am able to do this without difficulty.  However, I would like to keep this image completely static while dynamically drawing overlays on top of it.  With that in mind, it would be better if I could set the image as a permanent background of the panel, rather than having `paintComponent()` redraw the image every time.  This would be particularly useful, as there will frequently be situations where I want to `removeAll()` graphics currently on the panel and redraw new ones.

So my question is this:  is there a way to set a permanent background image in JPanel, or do I have to redraw the image every time `paintComponent()` is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can try putting the Jpanel inside another Jpanel. You draw the image on the container JPanel. then make your inner JPanel a transparent one. this way, when there are no objects on it, you see the background of the parent JPanel which did not change.

Comment: This sounds like what I'm looking for.  can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2):

- put `Image` as `Icon / ImageIcon` to the `JLabel`
- use this [`JLabel` instread of `JPanel`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140800/why-to-add-jpanel-to-a-jlabel-under-what-circumstance-this-situation-can-arise)
- [JLabel hasn't implemented any LayoutManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575641/how-returns-xxxsize-from-jcomponents-added-to-the-jlabel) in compare with `JFrame(BorderLayout)` or `JPanel(FlowLayout)`
- you have to define the proper `LayoutManager`, that accepting PreferredSize came its child(s)
- then there are accesible (almost nearly) all methods as for JPanel, as container works